# How to delete duplicates from table with clob column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with a clob column, and I want to create a unique index on it.

But CLOB length is more than 4000 bytes.

How to insert all data from another table without duplicates without a CLOB error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count CLOB Duplicates in a large Oracle Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28907644/count-clob-duplicates-in-a-large-oracle-table)

Comment: Why would you want to create a unique index on `clob` ?

Comment: @DigvijayS . . . The question is really why a database would (arbitrarily) prevent a user from doing such a thing.  I am baffled by certain limitations in tools.  In this case, of course, the limitation is based on the underlying page size, but it can be hard to figure out why that is the case -- and why there isn't an alternative mechanism for enforcing uniqueness.

Comment: In my table 15 million data and 5 unique, i wanted to create new empty column and insert unique elements

Comment: The solutions in @wolφi 's link are probably the best option. Compute the hash on the CLOB column and compare the hashes. If you are concerned about false positives (different CLOB values with the same hash), you could store both the hash of the entire value and the first character of the CLOB (the probability of collision becomes a lot smaller still). Or, if all your CLOB are of limited length - say up to 12k characters - you can chunk the CLOB and store the pieces, then have a unique index on those columns. Don't expect any of these solutions to have good performance.